# Convert this Custom round into a more math-friendly solution

Tags: c++, math

Yes I would like to know if there is a way to convert this logic, into a more mathfriendly solution. For one, I would like to learn a bit more math, two I am curious about if it is possible.

*edit* Yes yes, some of the lines are redundant, or not typesafe etc etc, can we please stick to the question at hand people? :)

The goal is to round down each quarter to it's previous quarter if not above it.

**Example:**

> 0.25 = 0,
>   0.27 = 0.25,
>   0.50 = 0.25,
>   0.52 = 0.50,
>   0.75 = 0.50,
>   0.78 = 0.75

```
float lulzRound(float value)
{
    int integer = (int)value;
    float start = value - (float)integer;
    float result;
    if(start < 0.25)
    {
        result = 0;
    }
    else if((start > 0.25) && (start <= 0.50))
    {
        result = 0.25;
    }
    else if((start > 0.50) && (start <= 0.75))
    {
        result = 0.50;
    }
    else if((start > 0.75) && (start < 1))
    {
        result = 0.75;
    }
    return (float)integer + result;
}
```

Comment: What does "math-friendly" mean?!

Comment: For your own sake, never use C-style casts. For the readers', please indent your code. Lastly, the code is broken, as it doesn't handle every possible `value`, and I'm not even going into NaNs or INFs.

Comment: Why the asymmetry (0.50 becomes 0.25 and 0.75 becomes  0.50)?

Comment: @DieterLücking: Because thinking about boundary conditions is hard... What about `if (start == 1)`? :-)

Comment: @DieterLücking Rating ratio requires it, do not ask me why, but it just does :)

Comment: What is the result for `0.25`?

Comment: @Danvil 0 is what we would want then :)

Comment: @Hiam: You code does not do this ;)

Comment: @KerrekSB it means if there is any way to solve the above logic with just math instead :)

Comment: @Danvil It does on my system, however i will not say that is not the case for you, you might end up with different precision from what I have or that your compiler does something differently, at anycase, the logic behind the code is not wrong :)

Comment: @Hiam: The first `if` is only true if `start < 0.25`, the second only if `start > 0.25`. The first `if` should check for `start <= 0.25`.

Comment: @Danvil ah yes, I see what you mean, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that would be this:

```
return floor(value*4.0)*0.25;
```

This translates a value of 0.25 into 0.25.  If you need to translate it into 0.0, use this:

```
return ceil(value*4.0)*0.25-0.25;
```

But be aware that this will also translate 0.0 into -0.25.  If that's not acceptable, you could use this:

```
return value < 0.25 ? 0 : ceil(value*4.0)*0.25-0.25;
```

Or another alternative:

```
return ceil(value*4.0)*0.25 - (fmod(value,1) ? 0.25 : 0);
```

Here's a short test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

float round(float value)
{
    return ceil(value*4.0)*0.25 - 0.25;
}
int main()
{
    for (float i=0.0; i < 1.5; i+=0.05)
        std::cout << i << " ==> " << round(i) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Yes, however the above logic is slighly different than what you normally would expect, if we get a exact one-quarter, we need to round down to the previous one-quarter. (does that make any sense? If not check the example above)

Comment: Your new solution is somewhat what I am after, allthough the same thing you point out for 0.0 into -0.25 will also be the same for 2.0 which should not scale down to 1.75 but remain on 2.0

The code should work on numbers like 1245.75 or 1241.50 or 1415 if you catch my drift. I guess you could just do the same type of check as with the zero tho :)

Comment: I added a if(fmod(value, 1) == 0) into the mix, and it does translate well as a safeguard for the either 0.0 = -0.25 or 2.0 = 1.75 So yes, thanks a lot for your solution, it did do what I was after :)

Answer (score 1):

```
float lulzRound(float value) {
    value *= 4.0f;
    int i = static_cast<int>(value);
    if(i > 0 && value == static_cast<float>(i)) {
        i--;
    }
    return static_cast<float>(i)*0.25f;
}
```

This code works for `value >= 0` as you specified. For negative numbers it does something similar.

Comment: Interesting approach... It did sum up the logic together, even tho I was originally asking if this could be solved with math, You did a fair job of optimizing the logic :) Thanks

Comment: @Hiam If `lulzRound(0)` should result in 0, than you can not do without an `if` statement.

Comment: @Hiam: And keep in mind, that my code uses exactly the same number of casts then your original code. In particular it does not require an additional math function like `ceil`.

Comment: Your solution is also very nice, it does the trick, and from a programming standpoint, probably better than the accepted answer, because it does not rely on anything else than just code :) I upvoted your answer, but accepted the answer from @Edward cause it matched the original critiera of this post better :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to round to units of one-quarter. Something like this:

```
int(value * 4) / 4.0     // [0.00, 0.25) -> 0.00
                         // [0.25, 0.50) -> 0.25
                         // [0.50, 0.75) -> 0.75
                         // [0.75, 1.00) -> 0.75
```

Or this:

```
int(value * 4 - 1) / 4.0 // [0.00, 0.25) -> -.25
                         // [0.25, 0.50) -> 0.00
                         // [0.50, 0.75) -> 0.25
                         // [0.75, 1.00) -> 0.50
```

Comment: Does not give the correct result for example for `value = 0.75`.

Comment: @Danvil: I added another option.